# Android Notification Bar Build Method Error

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need some help as I am new to Android.  I cannot seem to grasp how to build a new Notification.Builder instance.  Sadly the tutorial I am following uses an older constructor, which after perusing the android reference docs clearly states.  I have created a button that when you press just provides a simple notification.  All the code seems ok after finding other examples, but I get an red line error in Eclipse under the build method.  Any help would be much appreciated:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Context context = Main.this;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(Main.this, 0, intent, 0);

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(Main.this)
    .setTicker("This is important!")
        .setContentTitle("PLEASE READ!")
        .setContentText("Important message from me!")
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setContentIntent(pending)
        .build();


    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(0, noti);
    }
});
```

Comment: Whats the error message that eclipse is giving you?

Answer (score 1):

`Notification.Builder.build()` is API level 16. You probably have not set the target to v16 and/or downloaded the v16 android development kit, so that Eclipse does not know about that method and thus flags it as invalid.

Have a look at the documentation for [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#build%28%29)

Comment: Thank you for your time, that does sound about right as I am working at 4.0.3 as my Samsung Galaxy is not on 4.1 yet.  I did look at the Notification.Builder documentation but couldn't quite work it out due to methods being "depreciated" amongst other.  So what would be the correct way to implement it on API 15.  Thanks

Comment: Just an update, I took out the build() method and replaced it with a depreciated .getNotification() method and it seems to work on my phone, but I have a feeling its not fully correct.

Comment: For the moment I think it is as correct as it can get. Just because a method is deprecated does not mean it is incorrect. It just means that you should use something better if possible.

Comment: Thanks again, after perusing the documentation a little deeper, I did notice actual API version numbers directly adjacent to the methods so I will pay great attention to them in future.  Getting there but a long way off at the moment! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android.support.v4, use NotificationCompat found in [Android v4 Support](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)